# How to get the month difference for each record in temp table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #t ( ID INT, V FLOAT, D DATE )

INSERT  INTO #t
VALUES  ( 1, 1, '2014-07-01' ),
        ( 1, 2, '2014-08-02' ),
        ( 1, 3, '2014-09-03' ),
        ( 2, 7, '2014-10-31' ),
        ( 2, 5, '2014-11-28' ),
        ( 2, 8, '2014-12-31' ),
        ( 2, 11, '2015-01-30' );
```

I would like to find the month difference for each record in my temp db from today's date which is March 14 2015.
And the final table should look like this

```
   ( 1, 1, '2014-07-01', 9),
    ( 1, 2, '2014-08-02', 8),
    ( 1, 3, '2014-09-03', 7),
    ( 2, 7, '2014-10-31', 6 ),
    ( 2, 5,  '2014-11-28', 5),
    ( 2, 8,  '2014-12-31', 4),
    ( 2, 11, '2015-01-30', 3);
```

For this record  ( 2, 11, '2015-01-30', 3);  the date falls on Jan month while my current month is March so March -Jan 2015 should be 3.

Any suggestion would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH, D, GETDATE())
```

The "MONTH" argument asks for months though you might need to add one to the result to get the results you're after.

Comment: A small change: `+ 1`

Comment: [Why `M` instead of `MONTH`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx)?

Comment: Fair point, and it makes sense to use the full version for the sake of clarity.  I'll edit.